# How to create Gateway on E-MapReduce Console

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

As Gateway is an ECS Server in the same intranet as the e-MapReduce Cluster in Alibaba Cloud. How I can use Gateway to achieve Load Balancing and Security Isolation in Alibaba Cloud ECS.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite get your question:
1, isolation, VPC/security group is isolation layer in Alibaba Cloud, not sure what kind of isolation you are refering to.
2, Load Balancing: MapReduce master should be able to dispatch the job in a balanced way. What exactly LB you would like to achieve?

Comment: I was reading Gateway Documentation that You can use Gateway to achieve load balancing and security isolation, or submit jobs to the E-MapReduce cluster. Thats what I asked that How can I use Gateway to achieve and Load Balancing and Security Isolation.

Comment: could you please share the link to the document? Gateway refers to VPN gateway or NAT gateway or which gateway?